# make force target before prequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know this has been asked before, but please bear with me. run_test is the name of the file I would like to make. I prefer invoking as 'make run_test'. I want the prereq's makefile to be called each time I call make run_test. But I don't want the call to the prereq's make to force run_test to be rebuilt.

```
run_test: build_prereq prereq_dir/prereq_ts
  rebuild_test.sh

.PHONY: build_prereq

build_prereq:
  make -C prereq_dir
```

prereq_dir/prereq_ts is updated if make -C prereq (prereq_dir/makefile) detects that prereq's dependencies are old and prereq needs to be rebuilt.

The problem with this is that rebuilt_test.sh is always called, and I assume that is because one of run_test's dependencies is executed (as it is PHONY).

I have resolved this issue by changing run_test to:

```
run_test:: build_prereq

run_test:: prereq_dir/prereq_ts
  rebuild_test.sh

.PHONY: build_prereq

build_prereq:
  make -C prereq_dir
```

Is this a good solution? This first runs build_prereq, and then it runs rebuild_test.sh if prereq_dir/prereq_ts is updated (which would happen in build_prereq's make call if needed).

Is there a more proper way of doing this. I do not want to create additional targets as that doesn't allow a direct call of make  ie 'make run_test'.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Suppose `prereq_dir/prereq_ts` has not changed, but the prerequisites of `prereq` have; should `make run_test` do anything?

Comment: No, run_test should not be rebuilt. If the prerequisites of prereq change, then prereq_dir/prereq_ts would be touched and that should cause run_test to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make supports exactly what you want.

```
.PHONY: build_prereq
build_prereq:
    ${MAKE} -C prereq_dir

prereq_dir/prereq_ts: build_prereq ; 

run_test: prereq_dir/prereq_ts
    rebuild_test.sh
```

So, you ask make to build `run_test`.

1. To ensure `prereq_dir/prereq_ts` is up to date it first runs the
   recipe for `build_prereq`.
2. Next it runs the recipe for `prereq_dir/prereq_ts` (which does nothing—see that `;`).
3. Now it checks the time-stamp of `prereq_dir/prereq_ts` to decide whether `run_test` is out of date.

Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to be non-portable, GNU make supports *order-only prerequisites* (see the GNU make manual) which do exactly what you want:

```
run_test: | build_prereq

build_prereq:
        $(MAKE) -C prereq_dir
```

(note *always* use `$(MAKE)` when invoking sub-makes, never `make`)

Comment: No, this does not work when `prereq_dir/prereq_ts` is (i) possibly touched when `build_prereq` runs and (ii) is a normal pre-req of `run_test`.